# send email using twitter-bootstrap modal, json, and wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, email, twitter-bootstrap

I'm needing to collect a Name and Email through a twitter-bootstrap modal that sends me an email  and updates the modal window 'success' upon submit using the wordpress platform. Can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing would be to use Gravity Forms (or similar) to handle the form bit, use the Form widget to add the form to a widget area, then include that widget area on the page where you want to use the modal.

For example (using Gravity Forms):

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('form-sidebar');?>
</div>

<a href="#myModal"  data-toggle="modal">This is the link that triggers the modal</a>
```